# "Background" Game animations with javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance, canvas

Suppose my base class is the following:

```
function Tile(obj) {
    //defaults (alot of variables here like colors and opacity)
}
Tile.prototype.Draw = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.Red + "," + this.Green + "," + this.Blue + "," + this.Opacity + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, this.Width, this.Height);
};
```

my class that inherits from the Tile class

```
Apple.prototype = new Tile();
Apple.prototype.constructor = Apple;
function Apple(obj) {
    Tile.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

So what I would like to do with my apple objects is have its opacity fluctuate between 0 and 1 so that it constantly fades in and out but I would like this to happen independently of the 'game loop'. (So that the fading animation is smooth regardless of the game speed)

```
    function StartGameLoop() {
        console.log("*** Starting Game ***");
        gameLoop = setInterval(Game, gameSpeed);
    }

    function Game() {
        if (!IS_GAME_ON) {                          // Did the game end?
            EndGame();
        } else if (!PAUSE) {                        // Is the game not paused?
            console.log("Tick");
            Logic();                                // do any math
        }
    }
```

I can't wrap my head around how to do this but I had an idea of putting a setInterval in the Apple constructor that calls the draw function over and over again but I can't get it to work. Like this:

```
Apple.prototype = new Tile();
Apple.prototype.constructor = Apple;
function Apple(obj) {
    var AnimationDirection;
    var animate = setInterval(this.Draw, 50);
    Tile.apply(this, arguments);
}
Apple.prototype.Draw = function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.Red + "," + this.Green + "," + this.Blue + "," + this.Opacity + ")";
    ctx.fillRect(this.X, this.Y, this.Width, this.Height);

    if (this.Opacity <= 0) {
        this.AnimationDirection = 0.1;
    }
    else if (this.Opacity >= 1) {
        this.AnimationDirection = -0.1;
    }

    this.Opacity += this.AnimationDirection;
};
```

It works as you'd expect when the first Apple.Draw() is called but the calls from the setInterval are not working properly. Any ideas?

(PS: Also the two ctx lines in the Draw function are repeated in both the Tile and the Apple classes, is there any way I can kick it to the Tile parent for the filling instead of having the code duplication?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the cause is that when the `Draw()` function fires as part of the `setInterval` call, `this` isn't what you think it is.

Instead, use a variable inside your constructor to store the value of `this` when it refers to the Apple object created, and use an anonymous function for `setInterval()` to be able to refer to that new variable and call the `Draw()` function correctly on it, e.g. something like:

```
function Apple(obj) {
    var AnimationDirection, me = this;
    var animate = setInterval(function() {
        me.Draw();
    }, 50);
    Tile.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Since you are now calling the `Draw()` method on an `Apple` object (rather than the global window), `this` will correctly refer to that object.

Comment: You might also be able to avoid duplication by using `Tile.Draw.apply(this)` in your Apple's `Draw()` function instead of the two `ctx...` lines.

Comment: Also, the following article may help clarify some things related to this for you: http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx